# Doing a join on multiple tables based on the id's returned in a subquery and keeping that order

Tags: mysql, join, stored-procedures

Here's a tricky one (or so I think). I have a stored procedure that looks like the following:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`dev-user`@`%` PROCEDURE `geospacial`(IN _lat double, IN _lng double, IN _distance double, IN _limit int)
BEGIN

set @radius = _distance;
set @lng_min = _lng - @radius / abs(cos(radians(_lat)) * 111);
set @lng_max = _lng + @radius / abs(cos(radians(_lat)) * 111);
set @lat_min = _lat - (@radius / 111);
set @lat_max = _lat + (@radius / 111);

SELECT DISTINCT
    `project_id`

FROM (
    SELECT
         `project_id`,
         ROUND((6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(`lat`)) * COS(RADIANS(`long`) - RADIANS(_lng)) + SIN(RADIANS(_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(`lat`)))), 2) AS distance

    FROM
        geodata

    WHERE
        (`long` BETWEEN @lng_min AND @lng_max)

    AND
        (`lat` BETWEEN @lat_min and @lat_max)

    ORDER BY
        CAST(distance as DECIMAL(10,5)) ASC
) as _geo

;END
```

When called, it returns the ID's of the projects that have a point closest the the given lat/lng, although these details may not be important. Given the results I have now, am I able to create an outer query around the `SELECT DISTINCT...` query that will get all the projects with those given id's, joined with a few other tables based on the project id. I know I can use a `WHERE IN`, but I then loose the order of the ID's (the order is important).

Any SQL way of doing this in one request? The best best option I can think of is storing these ID's in a temp table, then doing my select/joins on that based on the project_id.

Comment: You should check mySql spatial extension, that will make your life easier. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html

Comment: aditional tip, if you save your sin and cos calculation in variables, your query will be much faster ... `@l_acos = ACOS(COS(RADIANS(_lat))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do what you want using `group by` and `order by` in the outer query:

```
SELECT project_id
FROM (SELECT project_id,
             ROUND((6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(`lat`)) * COS(RADIANS(`long`) - RADIANS(_lng)) + SIN(RADIANS(_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(`lat`)))), 2) AS distanc
      FROM geodata
      WHERE (`long` BETWEEN @lng_min AND @lng_max) AND
            (`lat` BETWEEN @lat_min and @lat_max)
     ) gd
GROUP BY project_id
ORDER BY MIN(CAST(distance as DECIMAL(10,5))) ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you, much easier than I expected it to be!